# javascript - change filename

Tags: javascript, batch-file, dos, filenames

I would like to use JavaScript or a DOS script to add some words before and after the original filename. Have you any script I can use?

ORIGINAL:

```
AAAA.pdf  
BBBB.pdf  
CCCC.pdf  
CCCC_01.pdf  
CCCC_02.pdf  
CCCC_03.pdf  
CCCC_04.pdf  
DDDD.pdf  
EEEE.pdf
```

Target:

```
999_AAAA_333.pdf  
999_BBBB_333.pdf  
999_CCCC_333.pdf  
999_CCCC_333_01.pdf  
999_CCCC_333_02.pdf  
999_CCCC_333_03.pdf  
999_CCCC_333_04.pdf  
999_DDDD_333.pdf  
999_EEEE_333.pdf
```

Comment: Javascript can't access files.

Comment: @Barmar, they said `java script`. I guess they were thinking a Java executable was a script.

Comment: I want change the filename

Comment: `999_CCCC_01_333` would be easier than `999_CCCC_333_01` ... will it always be 4 characters that you want to add the extra parts around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the letters are always 4 digits long, you can do this, which will insert the `999_` at the front, and the `_333` right after the the 4 digits of letters:

```
@echo off

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

cd /d c:\folder\with\pdf\files

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir *.pdf /b') do (
  set fn=%%i
  ren %%i 999_!fn:~0,4!_333!fn:~4,-3!.pdx
)

ren *.pdx *.pdf

endlocal
```

The `ren` in the `for` loop intentionally renames the `.pdf` files to `.pdx` so that the `for` loop won't pick up the renamed files again and perform the rename a second time.  Then all the `.pdx` files are renamed to `.pdf`...